# Questions regarding luggage pick up in Delhi in transit

Tags: visas, transit, india, south-african-citizens, nepal

I am a South African citizen arriving in Delhi en route to Kathmandu and the problem is I am flying in on one airline and departing on another so I have to collect my luggage in Delhi. I am returning to Delhi after 13 days and will stay in Delhi for 3 nights.

Can I purchase 2 single entry visas for this purpose as I don't have time to apply for a multiple entry visa?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can get two electronic single entry permits for free from [HERE](https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/visa/info1.jsp)

Remember to print out both Permits to show each at Indian border control (and at the flight gate if asked)

You don't need an actual visa to enter India for max 30 days, except if having entered more than twice in a calendar year.

Comment: Dude, Indian "e-tourist-visa" is not free - it's about 30 bucks right?

Comment: @JoeBlow Depends on nationality. 100% free for South Africans https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/visa/eTV_revised_fee_final.pdf

Comment: Bizarre!  Good spot.  The fee is about USD50.  For a handful of countries (including South Africa, where the OP is from!) it is free.

Comment: @JoeBlow There are 4 price Levels: free, USD 25.62, 49.1 and 61.5 (there's a 2.5% fee on top of the listed fees)

Comment: Right, the vast majority are 48 bucks (annoyingly the US & UK are 60 bucks!)  Plus a card fee to either SBI or Axis.  Great spot that South Africa is free.